# Send non blocking requests in while loop

Tags: python, request, python-3.6

I'm currently creating a small application (in python 3.6) and have some problems with sending a non blocking request to a server.

This is my code:
`def foo():
    x = get_input_and_pre_process() # synchronous
    send_non_blocking_request(x) # don't await response of the request
    do_something_else(x)  # synchronous
while True:
    foo()`

So basically the case is the following:
I'm reading live data from an input and once I made some small changes to it, I want to send it to a server. But since I'm reading the data live I cannot afford awaiting the answer from the server and want to immediately continue with `do_something_else()` after sending the request and then continue with the next iteration of the while loop.
I'm not expecting any special response from the server, the key point is just to send out the data.

I read some articles about asynchronous programming with asyncio and aiohttp, but I'm not sure if this does the job here.
I also thought about executing the requests in a new thread but then I would be spawning thousands of new threads in the while-loop (which is also not that great of an idea I guess).

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Both asyncio and threads can do this fine. You can use a pool to limit the number of outgoing requests instead of thousands—you'll definitely want to do that with threads; it may not be necessary with asyncio, but if all of the requests are going to the same server, you'll probably do better with a pool anyway. Both `concurrent.futures` (for threads) and `asyncio` have examples in the docs showing what you want to do. And of course there are third-party libs like `requests-futures` and `aiohttp` that also have good examples.

Comment: Anyway, nobody can tell you what's the "best" way to do this. The answer depends on a lot of different things—from details about your server and requests that we don't know, to which style of programming you feel more comfortable with or find easier to learn. So you'll have to look through the examples yourself to get a feel for what seems like it'll work for you, then try to build something.